# One bundle from adapter and another bundle from main activity is sent to one fragment || How to receive both bundle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-fragmentactivity

- I am sending one bundle from an adapter and one bundle from main activity and receive both in fragment. I can get the data for first bundle i.e, pass from adapter but for second bundle i.e, from main activity I cannot retreive. How to do this? I have tried so hard but cant make it work. Please help thank you*

```
// Adapter... sending data to fragment

                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("contents", sContents[10]);
                    bundle.putString("details",sDetails[10]);
                    bundle.putInt("position",getPosition());
                    bundle.putBundle("bundle",bundle);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);


//Main Activity //sending data to fragment
                                 Bundle passSize=new Bundle();

                                 passSize.putString("selection",selection);

                                 passSize.putBundle("passSize",passSize);

                                 fragment.setArguments(passSize);


//Fragment  //Receiving data from adapter and Main Activity
          if(bundle!=null) {
            if(bundle.getBundle("bundle")!=null) {
                String myValue = bundle.getBundle("bundle").getString("details");
                position = bundle.getBundle("bundle").getInt("position");

            }
          }

     //Here not working...... Note: the passing data is correct and No error when debug or run. 
            if(bundle.getBundle("passSize")!=null){
                System.out.println("inside bundle");
                if(bundle.getBundle("passSize").getString("selection")!=null){
                    .
                    .
                    .
                }

            }
```